# How can alum stone be melted and molded into small shapes?

Tags: alternatives, manufacturing, personal-hygiene

We are a small NGO in Nepal working to help people after the recent earthquakes of 2015 and now the floods of this year's monsoon of 2017. There is a stone here that is used as an astringent/after shave when men go to the barber for a shave. Our agency would like to mold this stone into a small soap-shaped bar to sell as a fundraiser. As it turns out, it is an excellent hand sanitizer and I've used it for years, since moving to Nepal 7 years ago. This is the same stone being used for deodorant bars. It is called [alum stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alum) or fitkiri.

We will be ever so grateful for any suggestions. It melts at a low temperature, but we cannot get it to hold together as it solidifies. Every time I have shown a guest the stone they've been eager to have one. If we can mold it into a small shape it will help to keep many people from getting the typical traveler's stomach upset. This is even more important for people going up into the Himalayas.

Comment: Do you know the chemical composition of the stone? I'm assuming _alum_ indicates it contains aluminum?

Comment: @LShaver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alum "An alum block sold as an astringent in pharmacies in India (where it is widely known as Fitkari (Hindi) or Phitkari (Urdu)"

Comment: It looks like you can't. From https://www.revolvy.com/topic/Alum: *When heated, they liquefy, and if the heating is continued, the water of crystallization is driven off, the salt froths and swells, and at last an amorphous powder remains*

Comment: I don't think you can mould it, but one can relatively easily grow large single crystals of Alum (it is a popular childrens' science experiment).  Google "growing Alum crystals" for info.  I don't know how easy it would be to scale this process up however.  Another alternative may be to press powder/fine crystals together - though you would need some form of binder and would need to invest in machinery.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different materials called alum.  The most common, is potassium aluminum sulfate.

KAl(SO4)2 * 12 H2O

The material is very soluble in hot water, and melts at 92.5 C (less than boiling point for water.)

Because of it's general solubility, I don't know if the stones sold are pure alum.  You may want to add some form of filler that would reduce the water contacting the surface.  I would suggest trying talc powder. (baby powder), or cabosil (fumed silica).  Avoid organic fillers such as corn starch, husks, psyllium as they will likely mold or mildew.

Methods of prep:  Haven't done this.  This advice worth what you paid for it.

1a.  Barely cover the bottom of a pan with water, and get it hot.  Add alum crystal to it.  As they dissolve, keep adding more.  Continue until you have a temperature just under the melting point.  A cheap electronic thermometer may be useful.

or

1b.  Put alum in the upper pot of a double boiler, and let it heat with a lid on it until it melts and is clear.

2. Stir in filler compounds. How much?  Experiment.
3. Pour into molds.